# App Preview, how to add blank audio track in iMovie? or ffmpeg?

Tags: ios, iphone, ffmpeg

Apple (customer support) is telling me that I must have audio in my app preview.

My question is, how do I add a blank audio track to my mp4 app preview file?

Or is there some other way I can get my app preview approved without having audio?

There are many reasons why I dont want audio in my app preview. 1) I dont want to add some weird music in there thats not copyrighted. 2) I'm not going to narrate my app.

Comment: I have not read the specific part about audio, however, if they say you must have audio, I am positive they don't mean "a blank audio track to your mp4" .

Comment: They won't approve without Audio, you can try `iMovie` iOS App, or Mac App to add audio they have good set of audio, no copyright problem, that will help.

Comment: @iphonic out of curiosity, what do you normally do for your audio? Do you narrate it? Do you add music?

Comment: @toast If your app is a game music goes well, other than that you may choose soft music and text which highlights features of the recording, a voice over is great [check this](https://www.apptamin.com/blog/app-previews/)

Comment: @iphonic ok, thanks.